# Where to put "too" when using fronting?

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

Where to put words like *either* or *too* when we are using fronting in a sentence? Take for example the sentence:

> She is a nice rhinoceros, **too**.

Will *too* remain at the end if we put the object first?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether

> A nice rhinoceros she is, too.

is a well-formed sentence, the answer is yes.   If you're asking whether the sentence

> A nice rhinoceros, too, she is.

is well formed, the answer is still yes.